# "stroke" css property is not working in my svg

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

actually i'm new at animating svg with css, i want to animate my svg like check marked animation, but i find that many people in youtube use "stroke" css property, but it doesn't make any change to my svg, but it still fine when i filled the color to my svg

here is the code

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container svg {
    width: 50%;
}

#circle {
    fill: red;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: animating 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes animating{
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 90 112.5" x="0px" y="0px">
            <path d="M45,77A32,32,0,1,1,77,45,32.036,32.036,0,0,1,45,77Zm0-62A30,30,0,1,0,75,45,30.034,30.034,0,0,0,45,15Z" id="circle"/>
            <path d="M40.5,53.5a1,1,0,0,1-.707-.293l-6-6a1,1,0,0,1,1.414-1.414L40.5,51.086,53.793,37.793a1,1,0,0,1,1.414,1.414l-14,14A1,1,0,0,1,40.5,53.5Z" class="mark"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *circle* is not an actual circle, this shape is a hollowed circle and the `stroke` you see is actually the `fill`, which cannot be animated using `stroke-dashoffset`.

```html
<path d="M45,77A32,32,0,1,1,77,45,32.036,32.036,0,0,1,45,77Zm0-62A30,30,0,1,0,75,45,30.034,30.034,0,0,0,45,15Z" id="circle"/>
```

You should use a real `circle` shape and then be able to animate its `stroke-dashoffset` like this:

```html
<circle r="25" cx="45" cy="45" id="circle"/>
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container svg {
    width: 50%;
}

#circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-dasharray: 500;
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
    animation: animating 3s ease-out both;
}

@keyframes animating{
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 90 112.5" x="0px" y="0px">
            <!--<path d="M45,77A32,32,0,1,1,77,45,32.036,32.036,0,0,1,45,77Zm0-62A30,30,0,1,0,75,45,30.034,30.034,0,0,0,45,15Z" id="circle"/>-->
            <!-- Use a real circle -->
            <circle r="25" cx="45" cy="45" id="circle"/>
            <path d="M40.5,53.5a1,1,0,0,1-.707-.293l-6-6a1,1,0,0,1,1.414-1.414L40.5,51.086,53.793,37.793a1,1,0,0,1,1.414,1.414l-14,14A1,1,0,0,1,40.5,53.5Z" class="mark"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i see, but how do you know that this is not an actual circle ? is that because of path element ? if so, "stroke" property won't work on path element? am i right ?

Comment: @LouisLeonardo I tried `stroke` directly on that `path`, it shows two concentric circles. Also, a circle with `path` isn't supposed to be that long, most of the cases you only need 4 nodes in `d` attribute.